# How many segments can I draw between $17$ points on the circumference of a circle so that each segment intersects all others inside the circle?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> A set of $17$ points is chosen on the circumference of a circle. Find
>   the maximum number of segments which can be drawn connecting pairs of
>   points such that each segment intersects all others inside,not on, the
>   circle.

Giving away one constraint of the problem I have $\dbinom {17}{2} $ segments which can be drawn between any two pair of points.

Now the segments which intersects all others on the circle are the ones which are found when we take a point on the circumference and calculate how many segments can be drawn from this point to any other point on the circumference,hence $17-1$ segments.

This happens for every point on the circumference,so I have $\cfrac {\dbinom {17}{2}}{16} $ segments which satisfy the constraint.

I haven't been able to find the solution of this problem on the Internet.  Can someone check my work ?

Edit: I've caught up the mistake it should have been $\cfrac {\dbinom {17}{2}}{17} $ since given a point on the circumference I am forming $17$ pairs.

Comment: $\frac{\binom{17}{2}}{16}$ is not a whole number...

Comment: I can't understand what's wrong.The arguments seems to be correct .Can you help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following: you have 17 possible endpoints to choose from in creating segments. If you use the same endpoint for two segments, those two segments will not intersect inside the circle:
[image]

Hence, each of your 17 endpoints can be used at most once, which means at most 8 segments can be drawn. In fact, you can also show that at least 8 segments can be drawn, by choosing pairs of endpoints that are roughly opposite (formally, if you number the endpoints going around the circle from $1$ to $17$, choose the segments $(1, 9), (2, 10), \ldots$).

[image]

Thus, you can draw 8 segments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 8 seems correct. As you observed, if there are 9 segments, then two of them will share a end-point and cannot intersect inside the circle.

Eight is possible: label them clockwise as $1,2,\ldots,17$ and join $i$ to $i+8$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are reading the problem correctly.  If we number the points $1$ through $17$ around the circle and draw the line from $1$ to $9$, it will not intersect the line from $2$ to $8$ inside the circle.  For the second line you need one endpoint in $[2,8]$ and one in $[10,16]$.  If you keep going you can get $8$